# I have upload laravel project in github but when download it on local machine it show old file of controller

Tags: php, github, laravel-5

In my office I put laravel 5 project in github but when I download It on my local machine it show old controller and old php class file.I have checked controller file it is latest file but on browser it show old controller

Comment: did you push your latest changes to your github repo .

Answer (score 0):

First go to your github and check the branch that you pushed your code and check that is it update or not, and if you find your new code in your github you just need to run this (if your branch name if `name`)

```
git checkout main
git pull origin main
```

And now you can check your local project and you should see your changes